# Recursively search single source file & all files imported/included in said file using Sublime Text (or other editor)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, search, vim, sublimetext3

**Overview**

I'll like to recursively search for a string in a selected source file. So the selected file will be searched, and all files imported into selected files, and files imported into those files, and so on.

I'm using *Sublime Text 3* so answers geared towards that would be ideal, but any answers on how to achieve this in other editors will be greatly appreciated as well.

**Goal/ What I want to do**

In code below is from a `Footer.jsx` file. I'll like to find any occurrences of the string `"container"` in Footer.jsx, but also in the files imported into `Footer.jsx`, and the files imported into those imported files and so on.

Ideally if it's possible to specify to only recursively search for files in a particular folder (ie. the source folder & not React libraries) that would be ideal. So in instance below, of the imported files, only `footerStyle.jsx` & 
`GridContainer.jsx` would be searched in the `Footer.jsx` file. Both files are relative to the `"src"` directory, which is defined in the `.env` file using `NODE_PATH=./src`

**What can presently be done & why its insufficient**

At present, I can search a single file (Ctrl+F), multiple files or all files (Ctrl+Shift+F), but not a single file and all files imported/included into that file recursively.

I could manually add the imported files in `Footer.jsx` to the *list of files to be searched*,  but this would require me to manually recursively traverse the imported files, & files imported in those files,etc to a sufficient depth and add all of those files to the search list. This of course can become very labour intensive. I'll just like to know if there are any existing tools to do this.

```
/* eslint-disable */
import React from "react";
// nodejs library to set properties for components
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
// nodejs library that concatenates classes
import classNames from "classnames";
// @material-ui/core components
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
// @material-ui/icons
import Favorite from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite";

import footerStyle from "assets/jss/material-kit-pro-react/components/footerStyle.jsx";
import GridContainer from "components/Grid/GridContainer.jsx";

function Footer(props) {
  const { children, content, classes, theme, big, className } = props;
  const themeType =
    theme === "transparent" || theme == undefined ? false : true;
  const footerClasses = classNames({
    [classes.footer]: true,
    [classes[theme]]: themeType,
    [classes.big]: big || children !== undefined,
    [className]: className !== undefined
  });
  const aClasses = classNames({
    [classes.a]: true
  });

  return (
    <footer className={footerClasses}>
      <div className={classes.container}>
        {children !== undefined ? (
          <div>
            <div className={classes.content}>{children}</div>
            <hr />
          </div>
        ) : (
          " "
        )}
        {content}
        <div className={classes.clearFix} />
      </div>
    </footer>
  );
}

Footer.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.oneOf(["dark", "white", "transparent"]),
  big: PropTypes.bool,
  content: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(footerStyle)(Footer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Vim has a feature called "include search" that does just that: `:help include-search`. It may need a bit of setup, especially for JavaScript and JSX, and a bit of practice but it's so worth it.

`[d` — Show definition of word under the cursor:

[image: Show definition of current word]

`[D` — Show list of possible definitions of `foo`:

[image: Show list of possible definitions of 'foo']

`gf` — Go to file under the cursor:

[image: Go to file under the cursor]

`[<C-d>` — Go to definition of word under the cursor:

[image: Go to definition of word under the cursor]

`:ilist /change` — Find all occurrences of word starting with `change`:

[image: Find all occurrences of word starting with 'change']

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to dynamically include the paths to your include definitions from a main file. You could probably create a plug-in that parses the file, pulls the import values and then populates the search fields.

Choose the menu **Find > Find in Files**, you get a form at the bottom:

- Find:
- Where:
- Replace:

In `Where`, just enter a comma-delimited list of the files references by your imports.

`Where:` path/to/file1.jsx,path/to/file2.js,path/to/more/file*.js

This will restrict your `Find` value to those files.

Comment: Thanks, Issue is that I'll need to recursively traverse the files manually and add files to the list up to a reasonable depth. This of course can become very labour intensive. I'm just wondering if there are any existing tools to do this.